# Strings to array

Tags: javascript, parsing

I've written a simple text tokenizer in JavaScript which works in my specific case, but I do not think it is maintainable (for example, if the requirement ever changed to allow newlines when surrounded by double quotes). **How can I simplify the algorithm** or abstract it better?

It should:

- strip out single-line comments (lines which begin with `#`)
- discard empty and whitespace-only tokens, except in the case where they are inside double quotes
- `throw` an error when there is an odd number of double quotes in the input

Example input:

```
# a "comment" with special characters
example 1

    "with multiple spaces" "    kept only inside double quotes"    and     not  outside
"side-by-side""double quotes without space in between""count as separate tokens"
```

Example output:

```
[
  "example",
  "1",
  "with multiple spaces",
  "    kept only inside double quotes",
  "and",
  "not",
  "outside",
  "side-by-side",
  "double quotes without space in between",
  "count as separate tokens"
]
```

A different approach I thought of instead of going through character-by-character is to use regular expressions (comments: `^#.*`, quoted tokens: `".*"`, unquoted tokens: `[^ ]+`, token separators: `\s`).

```js
const logTokens = (id) => console.log(parseTokens(id));

const parseTokens = (id) => {
  const input = document.getElementById(id).value;

  const tokens = [];

  var tokenBuffer = "";
  var insideDoubleQuote = false;
  var insideComment = false;

  for (const c of input) {
    // single-line comments end at EOF and upon new line
    if (insideComment) {
      if (c === "\n") {
        insideComment = false;
      }

      continue;
    }

    switch (c) {
      // single-line comments start with a "#"
      case "#":
        // single-line comments can only occur at the start of the line (token buffer empty)
        if (tokenBuffer === "") {
          insideComment = true;
        }
        break;

      case " ":
      case "\n":
        if (insideDoubleQuote) {
          if (c === "\n") {
            throw new Error("unterminated double quote");
          }

          // spaces inside double quotes should be kept (example: "this is a single token")
          tokenBuffer += c;
          break;
        }

        // ignore empty and whitespace-only tokens
        if (tokenBuffer.trim() !== "") {
          tokens.push(tokenBuffer);
        }

        // start next token
        tokenBuffer = "";
        break;

        // double quotes are not part of tokens
      case '"':
        // upon a matching double quote, it signifies the end of a token
        // this is the only case where empty and whitespace-only tokens are possible (i.e., "" and "  ")
        if (insideDoubleQuote) {
          tokens.push(tokenBuffer);

          // start next token
          tokenBuffer = "";
        }

        insideDoubleQuote = !insideDoubleQuote;

        break;

        // all other characters have no special meaning and are part of tokens
      default:
        tokenBuffer += c;
        break;
    }
  }

  if (insideDoubleQuote) {
    throw new Error("unterminated double quote");
  }

  // handle the case when the last line does not have a trailing newline
  if (tokenBuffer.trim() !== "") {
    tokens.push(tokenBuffer);
  }

  return tokens;
};
```

```css
button,
textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input" rows=10>
# a "comment" with special characters
example 1

    "with multiple spaces" "    kept only inside double quotes"    and     not  outside
"side-by-side""double quotes without space in between""count as separate tokens"
</textarea>
<button onclick="logTokens('input');">parse</button>
```

Comment: *How can I simplify the algorithm or abstract it better?*  ->  Take a look at the [official definition of the JSON object structure](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).  You can see how each "level" of named components breaksdown into nested levels of components with more specificity.  I get the sense that the algorithm has been virtually written for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're complaining about this code, and that's good,
it's the first step to fixing it.

The essential difficulty is that when we're asked to write down the
[single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
for `parse_tokens()`, we can't.
You eloquently summarized its actions as:

1. strip out single-line comments (/^#/)
2. throw an error when there is an odd number of double quotes
3. discard whitespace-only characters while tokenizing words, except in the case where they are inside double quotes

That sounds like three single-responsibility functions:

1. stripComment()
2. validateQuotes()
3. findTokens()

There's a fourth item wrapping all that: a loop
which reads newline-delimited lines and emits non-empty tokens.
Presumably we fail the entire input file if even a single line
fails to pass quote validation.

In bash we might organize this as a pipeline of three filter processes.
In python we might have co-routines `yield`ing strings or lists to each other;
many languages have similar idioms for this pattern.
In a language like C we might need some tedious `(result, err_status)`
tuples, or rely on a global like `errno`.
In JS or any other language that supports throwing exceptions
we can always rely on composition of functions:

```js
tokens = findTokens(validateQuotes(stripComment(line)))
```

Note that this is a partial function.
That is, we won't produce `tokens`
in the case where validation fails, and that's good.
The outer loop that reads lines should deal
with exceptions appropriately, perhaps by simply
letting them propagate up the call stack
so a single error will fail the whole input file.

Now we're in a good position to add three
separate unit tests to our automated test suite.